# WSO2 Identity server fundamentals -V5.11 : Cant run the "pickup-dispatch" application

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

so I'm trying to do the self-paced course WSO2 Identity server fundamentals -V5.11 "implementing access delegation for web/mobile apps" Section Access delegation -oauth 2.0.

-ive setup "localhost.com" in etc/host file.

-ive got tomcat8 running and it says pickup-dispatch is "running true" at localhost:8080/manager/html.

-I've downloaded and running backend-service.jar (does this need to be located in some certain file or path?)

-I have setup call-back URL as a service provider and edited dispatched.properties at /web-inf/classes to the correct consumerkey and consumer secret from service provider.

So i can't get to the http://localhost.com:8080/pickup-dispatch/index.jsp, but I can access http://localhost:8080/pickup-dispatch/index.jsp and I get to a login page
[Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGVHZ.png)

When I click Login I get "this site can't be reached"

I can't figure out what the problem is, help is most appreciated

Comment: It seems like localhost.com is not set well in the /etc/hosts file. And what's the url you are redirected when you click on login button?

Comment: I got this on my etc/host file 

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1    localhost.com
# ::1             localhost


The url when im clicking on "login" is:
https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?client_id=mgOd70QTzloidG0tQJ7xD85Axy.....

When logging in with admin

I get redirected here: (its here i get "this site cant be reached)

http://localhost.com:8080/pickup-dispatch/oauth2client?code=71149448-8871-38b8-bd50.........